# How to properly secure form with CAPTCHA

Tags: php, curl

I am working on maintaining some page developed by someone other. I have noticed, that forms are secured by some kind of image CAPTCHA, which is generated every time user enters page. CAPTCHA is stored in hidden input named `check`, and value entered by user is compared with value from hidden input after submitting form.

I have tried to use cURL to read page and [parse](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) CAPTHA from that hidden input.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/form/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

$html = str_get_html($result);
$captcha = $html->find('input[name=check]');
var_dump($captcha[0]->value);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    "name"      => "Joe",
    "telephone" => "1423456789",
    "message"   => "Lorem ipsum",
    "auth"      => $captcha[0]->value,
    "check"     => $captcha[0]->value,
    "submit_f1" => "Send"
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

Running above script causes correct form submit. What is more, I have noticed, that I can simply overwrite `auth` and `check` values in post array:

```
    "auth"      => 123,
    "check"     => 123,
```

and form is being submitted correctly as well.

I realize that there is not 100% safe method to secure forms, but how can I protect my form a little more and make automated submitting a little harder.

Comment: If you can edit code than i will suggest you to use `google recaptcha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind any challenge-response system is that you keep the response (the code) hidden and only show the challenge (the image).

You would typically use session to accomplish this; you store the response in the session and show the challenge. Once the correct response is entered you can clear the response session variable to prepare the system for the next challenge.

The following code only serves to illustrate the idea.

### Showing CAPTCHA

```
session_start();

// generate the string you wish to show as captcha
$str = generate_captcha();
// and store inside session
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $str;

// show_captcha() would generate the image
echo show_captcha($str);
```

### Validating CAPTCHA

```
session_start();

if ($_POST['captcha'] === $_SESSION['captcha']) {
    unset($_SESSION['captcha']);
    // continue with form submission
} else {
    // yikes, it doesn't match
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use of the `$_SESSION` is the most common way to accomplish this;

1. Generate a random string and store it in the `$_SESSION`.
2. Draw that random string to a jpg and save it in a tmp folder.
3. Display the jpg to the user alongside the form.
4. Compare the input against the session value.

However, if the use of sessions is not available to you, the other (slightly less common) method is to use a hash;

1. Generate a random string `$ranstr`
2. Calculate `SHA256($ranstr . $SECRET)` where `$SECRET` is a long server-side secret value that you should change occasionally.
3. Draw `$ranstr` to a jpg and save it in a tmp folder.
4. Display the jpg to the user alongside the form. The form will also contain the result of the hash in a hidden field.
5. Recalculate `SHA256($POST['human_test'] . $SECRET)` and compare it against the value of the hidden field.

In both cases, it would be a good idea to add a cron to delete jpgs older than 1 hour or so.